# How to purge/clear the cache (?) after running the ConTeXt compiler?

Tags: fonts, compiling, context

I am currently trying to set up a book layout in ConTeXt and keep hitting a problem when compiling my document with `context`.

The thing is, I am experimenting a lot with different layout options and it seems to me, the compiler keeps older versions of the document in some kind of cache. This results in older layout options (e.g. background color of margin notes, fonts etc.) still being present in the final PDF, although I removed them completely from all files (I'm working with products and an environment file). Not even deleting all files from the current directory or compiling with the options `--purgeall` or `--purgeresult` (what are these options for, by the way?) helps. Only by explicitely re-defining all definitions I seem to be able to remove the problematic design elements.

Does anyone know, if there's some kind of cache kept elsewhere that I can delete?

Comment: I've never seen the behavior you describe, and as far as I know, ConTeXt does not keep any hidden cache files. Have you thought about the idea that it may be your pdf viewer that doesn't refresh the displayed file properly? As for the meaning of these options, there's an explanation at the ConTeXt wiki: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/purge_aux_files

Comment: I agree with Thomas but if you really want to clear the cache (which contains the format files and font cache) run `mtxrun --script cache clear`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Thomas and @Aditya for posting answers to this. After playing around a bit I noticed that I had also set up a project file for this component. This still contained a reference to an older environment file.

I was under the impression that linking environment files in component (or product) files would simply take precedence over all other environments, which obviously is not the case. Instead, both files are read at compile time, resulting in all kinds of weirdness. Removing the link in the project file solved my problem.

Thanks for your help. And my apologies for the confusion.